# Why there are __version__ strings in some modules of Python standard library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, version, standard-library

By accident I noticed that both [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) modules of python standard library have their `.__version__` attribute:

```
>>> import re, csv
>>> re.__version__
'2.2.1'
>>> csv.__version__
'1.0'
```

It surprises me as they are part of the standard library, so I would expect their version to be defined by `sys.version` (and `sys.version_info`).

I have noticed the values of the attributes are same for both Python 2.7.13 and 3.6.1, despite the modules have changed.

Are they just a kind of "code fossils" or are they somehow meaningful and programmers should pay attention to their values?

Comment: I think you mix the version of Python with a version of a library. If you for instance work with a Linux-3.16 OS, that does not mean that you have to run Firefox 3 on it to browse the web. Version numbers are *not* global.

Comment: Not an answer, I guess, but: *"On a case-by-case basis, standard library modules which are also released in standalone form for other Python versions MAY include a module version number when included in the standard library, and SHOULD include a version number when packaged separately."* ([source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/#id25))

Comment: Furthermore the standard library is usually a collection of packages with a specific version number. But development on the packages continue. So you could decide to use a "nightly build" version of `re` that perhaps provides some experimental features, but is not yet fully tested to include it in the standard library. Usually a standard library aims to select high quality packages that are more or less *reliable*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I miss the analogy? If I have module of **same** version (1.0 in case of `csv`) I expect it to behave the same. The docs indicate that a lot of changes happened to both modules between Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that the source version of the module on C did not change, only the source code of the python module has changed across different versions of python itself. Looking for source code in [python](https://github.com/python/cpython) repository can shed light into whole situation.

For example:

- [CSV C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_csv.c)
- [CSV Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/csv.py)

Comment: This is basically right. However, the versions for `re` currently seem to be out of sync: `re.__version__` gives 2.2.1, but `re.sre_compile._sre.copyright` gives 2.2.2.

Comment: @ekhumoro `sre` is C lib imported in python module `re`, which have it's own version, so their versions may not be equal

Comment: No, those versions should be the same, for exactly the reasons you gave in your answer. I think someone just forgot to update the python module the last time the C lib version was bumped. The csv module gets its `__version__` directly from its C lib, so it does not have that potential problem.

Comment: @ekhumorob, well, thats wierd, because `csv` imports version from C. Why `re` don't do so - it's better to ask Guido. I thought that `sre` and `re` are actually different packages.

Comment: It's not weird - the `re` module is a python wrapper around several other modules, including `src_parse` and `src_compile`. The `_src` C lib module is quite old and was created by a third-party, so its not surprising it doesn't define `__version__` (which is a much newer API). My first comment above was just meant for information, since the `re` module was specifically mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ekhumoro oh, i see. Anyway, thanks for question, i've learned something new :)

Comment: Isn't that a violation of [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)? The module has changed even if the native code behind it has not. Or it is only recommended by [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#id48) but not used for Python standard library modules?

Comment: @abukaj python versioning schema is compatible with semantic versioning, but that's not mean that she is semantic. But still it's strange that versions of packages dont change accross different python versions